# Write a function that returns an array of structs

Tags: ios, swift

I am learning swift and trying to write a function to return an array of structs. I have a struct called `Event`

Here is my code so far:

```
/// downloads a list of events for a specific team
static func getEventList(teamPermalink: String) -> [Event]
{
    var eventList = []

    var url = "http://\(baseURL)/\(teamPermalink)/events.json"
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest()
    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue())
    { (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        let json = JSON(data: data)
        for var j = 0; j < json.arrayValue?.count; j++
        {
            let obj = json[j]["title"].stringValue
            let e = Event(title: obj!)
            println(e.title)
            // add e to the array
        }
    }
    return eventList
}
```

This is throwing an error at `return eventList` saying :`'NSArray' is not convertible to '[Event]'`

What am I doing wrong here? And why cant I append the `Event` to `eventList` where I have the comment to add it to the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the block (the part after NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest) happens asynchronously. Your method will return before that code is fired most likely. Since retrieving your event list requires some unknown time to pass, a better solution might be to pass a block to this method that you call when the result comes back, passing in the event list then.

As to why you are getting an error, this is because you didn't give the compiler enough information to determine the type for the array, so it went with the default which appears to be NSArray. You should declare eventList like the following:

```
var eventList:[Event] = []
```

Comment: Your right I was so busy trying to understand the syntax of swift I didnt think of the async method, thanks! I might just call it synchronously.

Comment: Why not? This is for populating a table I might as well wait for the table to download before showing it.

Comment: If you perform a synchronous network request on the main thread, your app will become unresponsive to user interaction and freeze all UI updates. You should always put off slow synchronous actions (loading files, network requests, image processing) onto a background thread. The API you were using in your code handles that for you. If this method is where you are providing the data for your tableView, just update an eventList class property when the async request finishes and call reloadData (or related) on the tableView.